# Select items from a List where the children contain the items from another List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

And Category:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following method:

```
public List<Product> FilterProducts(List<Category> categories)
{
    // filtering code here
}
```

Question: How can I filter my products using a `List<Categories>` as parameter?

**EDIT:** One thing I forgot to mention is that if I have 2 categories I should be able to see only the products with the *category1* **AND** *category2*. What I've done so far has returned only products with category1 OR category2. Although inherit *IEquatable* use Intersect seems interesting I am comparing with the Id's for now.

Comment: I'll be that guy... What have you tried so far?

Comment: (from product in Products where Products.Any(p => categories.Contains(p.Category))

Comment: Just edited and still testing :)

Comment: If you need to "see only the products with the category1 AND category2." then you will need my first solution which using the `All` method. Here is how can rewrite with using Ids: `return products.Where(p => categories.All(c => p.Categories.Any(cat => cat.Id == c.Id)).ToList()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to return all the products which has **all** the provided categories in its `Categories` which means it selects product where it has category1 AND category2.

Then you need to use the `All` with the combination of `Contains`:

```
public List<Product> FilterProducts(List<Category> categories)
{
    return products.Where(p => categories.All(c => p.Categories.Contains(c))
                   .ToList();
}
```

If you want to return all the product where it **has it least one** cetegory from the provided categories which means it selects product where it has category1 OR category2.

Then you need to use `Any`

```
public List<Product> FilterProducts(List<Category> categories)
{
    return products.Where(p => categories.Any(c => p.Categories.Contains(c)
                   .ToList();
}
```

Please not that if your `categories` objects are not the same instances which you have in the `Categories` property of the product or in your `Category` you are not overriding the `Equals` method to use the `Id` you may want to compare the `Id`s instead of the category objects themselves.

So something like:

The solution with **all**

```
public List<Product> FilterProducts(List<Category> categories)
{
     return products.Where(p => categories
        .All(c => p.Categories.Any(cat => cat.Id == c.Id)).ToList()
}
```

The solution with **any**

```
public List<Product> FilterProducts(List<Category> categories)
{
    return products.Where(p => categories
        .Any(cat => p.Categories.Any(pcat => pcat.Id == cat.Id)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: i think it must be the Any one

Comment: Please note that your usage may vary. If the two categories are semantically the same, but comes from different sources (ie they are not the same reference), this version of Contains is useless (as `Category` as we see it do not implement `IEquatable` or override the hashcode / equals method). You might want to do a comparison using lambda on the `Id`  if that's the case.

Comment: You can't return a lazy Linq iterator when your declared return type is `List<>`.

Comment: I am using List<myClass> like you are in your example, however, there is no Where method and give a compile error. I'm using VS 2015.

Comment: @James `Where` is an extension method defined in the System.Linq namespace. So make sure that you have the following using: `using System.Linq;`